# MariaDB equivalent to Oracle WHENEVER SQLERROR

Tags: mysql, error-handling, mariadb, sqlplus

In Oracle's sqlplus, when writing script we can use the `WHENEVER SQLERROR` to detect/handle errors.

e.g.

```
sqlplus /nolog -S <<EOF

WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT FAILURE ROLLBACK

CONNECT /

EXEC ThisProcThrowsAnError();

QUIT

EOF

if [ ${?} -eq 0 ]
then
   echo "Worked OK"
else
   echo "Oh dear"
fi
```

Is there an equivalent in MariaDB (`mysql` client)?

Note, I am not just interested in stored procedure, but essentially any errors that could error whilst executing a script on MariaDB.

Comment: You do know that you cannot use if conditions outside of stored programs in mariadb?

Comment: @PSalmon, Not sure I understand what you mean. The `if` in my example is outside the `sqlplus` HEREDOC, and is used to check the exist status of sqlplus, which would ne 1 if an error occurred. I'm simply asking if there is a way to get the `mysql` command to exit in a similar way if any of the commands within the script/session fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*In a MySQL / MariaDB stored procedure*, you can write this sort of thing, for example:

```
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
BEGIN
  ROLLBACK;
  @error := 'got exception';
END;
```

You can also write `DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR condition statement`.

Outside of a stored procedure, you cannot catch exceptions (except in a client program).

Here's the documentation. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/declare-handler.html

If you're looking for MySQL errors in a text file, you might try this regex

```
/^ERROR\s+\d{4}\s*([A-Z0-9]{5}):\s*.*$/
```

It looks for stuff like `ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '172.16.1.169'.`

Comment: It's like the Groucho Marx line: *Outside of a dog a book is man's best friend. Inside of a dog it's too dark to read.*

Comment: Thanks OJones. Let me the question another way then. If you had the scan the output of a mysql session for an error, what would you scan for? '^ERROR: [0-9]+' perhaps?

Comment: @OJones. I just saw your update on the regex. I think you answer shows the best that we can do with MariaDB.

Answer (score 0):

MariaDB 10.1 supports [Atomic Compound Statements](https://mariadb.com/resources/blog/atomic-compound-statements/). It allows you to create exception handlers outside of stored proceduces.

```
BEGIN NOT ATOMIC
  DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
  BEGIN  
   ROLLBACK;
   RESIGNAL;
  END;

  START TRANSACTION;

    stmt1;
    ....
    stmtN;

  COMMIT;
END
```